# How to return just file name using glob() in php

Tags: php, yii

How can I just return the file name. $image is printing absolute path name?

```
<?php
$directory = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/uploads/';
$images = glob($directory . "*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG}", GLOB_BRACE);
 foreach($images as $image)
   echo $image
?>
```

All I want is the file name in the specific directory not the absolute name.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Instead of `basename`, you could chdir before you glob, so the results do not contain the path, e.g.:

```
<?php
$directory = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/uploads/';
chdir($directory); // probably add some error handling around this
$images = glob("*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG}", GLOB_BRACE);
 foreach($images as $image)
   echo $image;
?>
```

This is probably a little faster, but won't make any significant difference unless you have tons of files

Answer (score 60):

Use php's [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

> Returns trailing name component of path

```
<?php
$directory = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/uploads/';
$images = glob($directory . "*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG}", GLOB_BRACE);
 foreach($images as $image)
   echo basename($image);
?>
```

Answer (score 26):

One-liner:

```
$images = array_map('basename', glob($directory . "*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG}", GLOB_BRACE));
```

Answer (score 23):

Use `basename()`

```
echo basename($image);
```

You can also remove the extension like this:

```
echo basename($image, '.php');
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at pathinfo

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Pretty helpful function

Answer (score 1):

Example extracting only file names and converting in new array of filenames width extension.

```
$dir =  get_stylesheet_directory();//some dir - example of getting full path dir in wordpress
$filesPath = array_filter(glob($dir . '/images/*.*'), 'is_file');

$files = array();       
foreach ($filesPath as $file) 
{
   array_push($files, basename($file));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're nervous about the unintended consequences of changing the working directory, you can store the current dir with `getcwd()` before changing, then simply use that value to switch back after you've done everything you need to do in that dir.

```
  <?php
  $directory = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/uploads/';
  $working_dir = getcwd();
  chdir($directory);
  $files = glob("*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG}", GLOB_BRACE);
  chdir($working_dir);
  ?>
```