# Laravel GLOB public path

Tags: php, laravel, path, glob

In Laravel I want to get all images from a dir, I just have a problem getting the path to the public folder.

```
    $images = [];

    foreach(File::glob('/public/img/uploads/*.*') as $filename) {
        $images[] = $filename;
    }
```

If I use this function it returns nothing, I also tried using `public_path()` but that returns the full path including my F:// dir.

Answer (score 6):

[Laravel glob function](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/143/finding-files-matching-a-pattern) returns an array with the absolute path of the files it found. It's important to remember that [you need to pass the absolute path in the argument too](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-glob-find-files/).

In your case, since you want to find files inside the public folder, you can use the [public_path()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#paths) helper as suggested by @Marcin Orlowski to get the desired absolute path; other helpers can be used in case you want to search in different locations.

So, the proper way to call glob in your code is the line below:

```
$images = File::glob(public_path() . '/img/uploads/*.*');
```

However, probably you don't want the absolute path, just the path relative to the public folder. In this case, you can use [the basename function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14366950/5696068) to get rid of the absolute path and add the path parts you want:

```
$images = [];
foreach (File::glob(public_path() . '/img/uploads/*.*') as $filename) {
    $images[] = '/img/uploads/' . basename($filename);
}
```

With [array map](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) instead of a foreach:

```
$images = array_map(function($filename) {
    return '/img/uploads/' . basename($filename);
}, File::glob(public_path() . '/img/uploads/*.*'));
```

**Note**: Laravel Glob is a wrapper for the [PHP glob() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).

Answer (score 0):

> I just have a problem getting the path to the public folder. I also tried using public_path() but that returns the full path including my F:// dir.

It does it as [manual reads](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#paths):

> base_path()
>   Get the fully qualified path to the root of the
>   application install.
>
> config_path()
>   Get the fully qualified path to the config
>   directory.
>
> public_path()
>   Get the **fully qualified path** to the public
>   directory.
>
> storage_path()
>   Get the fully qualified path to the storage
>   directory.

```
'/public/img/uploads/*.*'
```

I doubt your public directory is in your root folder and this is what your [absolute path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths) you used points to, so use what `public_path()` returns - it rather is nothing to bother it is full qualified path.